# Using JSON.stringify([element].serializeArray()) in AJAX - Internal Server Error

Tags: json, ajax, webforms

Using some pretty simple code, I'm trying to send a JSON string of form field values to a WebMethod on an .aspx page. I read a SO post that said to use `JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray())`. I'm not sure why, but when I try to send this as a string to my `WebMethod`, which accepts a `System.String` parameter, I get an HTTP 500 - the specific message: *Type "System.String" is not supported for deserialization of an array.*

Researching this error, a post suggested setting my parameter as a `string[]` instead of a regular string. Doing this 1.) doesn't make sense to me, since I though stringify should actually return a string, and 2.) returned a new error: *No parameterless constructor defined for type of "System.String".* To be clear, the AJAX method itself is failing, it never gets to the server side code.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label for="first_name" runat="server">Your Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="first_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label for="model_number" runat="server">Model Number</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="model_number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <button type="button" onclick="registration(); return false;">Test Customer Registration</button><br />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**:

```
    function registration() {
        var formData = $('#form1')
            .find("input,textarea,select,hidden")
            .not("#__VIEWSTATE,#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,#__EVENTVALIDATION")
            .serializeArray();

        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/services.aspx/registrationdata',
            data: "{data: " + JSON.stringify(formData) + "}",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

**C#**:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    [ActionName("registrationdata")]
    public static string RegistrationData(string[] data)
    { 
        try
        {
            // Parse serialized string
            var newData = string.Join(" ", data);
            var whatever = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DAO.ProdReg>(newData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Response { Success = "false", Message = ex.Message, Code = "1" }); //Break point here
        }

        return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Response { Success = "True", Message = "Entry added", Code = "0" });
    }
```

Looking for an explanation on the errors and the right way to do this.